# Restrict a Smart Contract function to be callable only from a specific Smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, nft

I have 2 Smart Contracts: `A` & `B`. `B` has a function `onlyA()` which I want that **only** `A` can call. Below is my approach:

- Make B **Ownable**, then add the `onlyOwner()` modifier to `onlyA()`.
- Add the interface of `B` in `A` so that `A` can call the function `onlyA()` from say `callMe()`.
- Transfer ownership of `B` to `A` after deploying it.
- Now, user can call `callMe()`.

My usecase:

I'm building a Protocol Smart Contract (`A`) that has an NFT Contract (`B`) linked to it. I don't want anyone to **directly** mint an NFT from `B`, but **only** by calling a function `mintNFT()` in the Protocol Smart Contract (`A`) which in turn calls the function `onlyA()` in `B` which internally mints the NFT.

Protocol.mintNFT() -> NFT.onlyA() -> ERC721._mint()

So I was thinking of using the above approach I listed. But I have to add the **interface** of my NFT Smart Contract to my Protocol Contract which I don't want to do. It just seems to me like an **anti-pattern**. It is considered bad practice to add interfaces like this?

I would highly appreciate any suggestions for an approach different from the one listed above. Also, any suggestions on the overall **re-design** of my Protocol Smart Contracts are also welcome.

**Update:**

Since both contracts are part of the same project, I was also wondering about simply importing the NFT contract in the Protocol Contract rather than defining the NFT interface. Which one is a **better** way, gas-wise & Solidity best practices wise?

Answer (score 0):

> Make B Ownable, then add the onlyOwner() modifier to onlyA().

You can just create a new modifier that would restrict the function so only A can call it, and pass A's address inside of B's constructor, no need to use ownable.
Like

```js
contract B {
address addressA;

modifier onlyACanCall() {
    require(msg.sender == addressA);
}
constructor(address _A) {
    addressA = _A;
}
function onlyA() external onlyACanCall {
    // ... 
}
}
```

> But I have to add the interface of my NFT Smart Contract to my Protocol Contract which I don't want to do

This is extremely common in smart contracts, why would you want to avoid it?

Comment: I can't pass address _A in B's constructor as I have to deploy B before A. Because I have to pass address B in A's constructor since its function callB() has to call B(address B).onlyA(). This will require address B to be passed in A's constructor. That's why I wanted to make B Ownable

Comment: Since both contracts are part of the same project, I was also wondering about simply importing the NFT contract in the Protocol Contract rather than defining the NFT interface. Which one is a better way, gas wise & Solidity best practices wise?

Comment: @DiamondDust, if you can set everything in a single contract, (size and business logic are not an issue) that would make it more efficient than having two contracts communicating with each other. (If you know how to program in solidity).

Answer (score 0):

Make B Ownable, then add the onlyOwner() modifier to onlyA().

You can just create a new modifier that would restrict the function so only A can call it, and pass A's address inside of B's constructor, no need to use ownable. Like

Comment: I can't pass address _A in B's constructor as I have to deploy B before A. Because I have to pass address B in A's constructor since its function callB() has to call B(address B).onlyA(). This will require address B to be passed in A's constructor.